# Need formula for excel to calculate percentage of outcome with different duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Entries | Outcome | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 |  |
| a | 1 |  |
| b | 1 |  |
| b | 2 |  |
| c | 2 |  |
| c | 2 |  |

I want to be able to calculate the percentage of outcome in excel
For example percentage of 1 if the entry is a is 100%, but for b is 50 etc...

I did not try anything because i do not know what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide a countifs that does both by a countifs that does just the entries.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)/COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)
```

[image]